# column in my pandas Data Frame where both credit and debit are mixed, I want to create separate columns for credit and debit

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['Withdrawal (Dr)/ Deposit (Cr)']
Out[571]: 
0      214.82 (Cr)
1       50.00 (Dr)
2       50.00 (Dr)
3       50.00 (Dr)
4       19.00 (Dr)
    
785    161.00 (Dr)
786    155.45 (Dr)
787     69.00 (Dr)
788     51.00 (Dr)
789     73.00 (Cr)
Name: Withdrawal (Dr)/ Deposit (Cr), Length: 790, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['dr/cr'] = df['Withdrawal (Dr)/ Deposit (Cr)'].apply(lambda x: x.split("(")[1])
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['dr/cr'])
df = pd.concat([df,df2], axis = 1)
```

I hope that it will help. Or it will atleast give you an idea what you have to do

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you split the data based on the identifier. Also, you most likely want the number as numbers. Lets generate some data:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol':['214.82 (Cr)','50.00 (Dr)','50.00 (Dr)','50.00 
                     (Dr)','19.00 (Dr)','161.00 (Dr)','155.45 (Dr)','69.00 (Dr)',
                     '51.00 (Dr)','73.00 (Cr)'] })
```

I create new columns CR and DR based on the characters in the original column. Then I remove the string part. (You can do this with regEx tricks as well.) Lastly I convert the the figures into numbers for future use.

```
my_df['CR'] = my_df[my_df['mycol'].str.contains('Cr')]['mycol'].str.replace('\(Cr\)', '').astype(float)
my_df['DR'] = my_df[my_df['mycol'].str.contains('Dr')]['mycol'].str.replace('\(Dr\)', '').astype(float)
```